# How can I find the difference between the latest time and the earliest time?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a set of data from a program that I export; and it varies in range. Sometimes there will be 9 cells in a column and sometimes, like, 40, for example. The very first cell in the column, when exported to Excel, is text that I don't need and the columns after the final populated cell are blank cells that I don't need. How can I figure out the time difference between the last populated cell and the first one?

When exported, the data in each cell (that isn't the first cell or a blank cell) looks like this: `4/25/2018 12:10:00 AM`. Assuming column "B" is what I used, I tried the following formula:

```
=IF(B:B(ISNUMBER), (TEXT(MAX(B:B)-MIN(B:B), "hr:mm:ss")), "")
```

which (in my eyes) means "If the cells in B have a number, the difference between the max and min (latest and earliest) times will be found in hours:minutes:seconds, and the formula cell will be blank otherwise."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The biggest issue is that `MAX()` and `MIN()` will ignore text values and blanks, so all you need is:

`=MAX(B:B)-MIN(B:B)`

To format the result, just choose `Format > Cells...` from the menu and pick one of the Categories offered.

If you format the cell holding the result as a number, what you'll see is a decimal number giving the difference in days.  If you give it a custom format of `[h]:mm:ss`, it will display the result in hours, min, and secs, even if the hours are greater than 24.

If you specify a format of `hh:mm:ss`, it will display the hours as less than 24 and not show any of the days that were (or might have been) there.  There is no hour format of "`hr`".

See this reference on how to use [`ISNUMBER()`](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-isnumber-function).  If you had written it correctly as `ISNUMBER(B:B)`, it would return an array of `True/False` values for the entire column.

I hope this helps, and good luck.

Comment: Hiya, @fix.  I saw your msg in the chat and answered.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with your formula. But a simple modification in the formula is required to execute it properly.

You need to be sure that,

1. The data range where you have imported Date & Time must be formatted as "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss Am/PM" or "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss".
2. The cell where you are calculating the time difference has to be formatted as General.

Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

The formula in cell D57 is `=IF(ISNUMBER(C57:C62),TEXT(MAX(C57:C62)-MIN(C57:C62),"HH:mm:ss"),"")`

Note: Please adjust the data range as necessary.